# add Second VLAN2 when eth0.2 exists. Linux

Tags: vlan, ifconfig

Currently I have eth0.2 VLAN, on vlan2, works great.

How can i add second VLAN 2?
would eth0.2:2 work?

Running CENTOS 6
Thank you. er

I did try:

```
[root@computer ~]# dhclient eth0.2:2
sysfs read broadcast value: No such file or directory
falling back to default broadcast value


ifconfig eth0.2:2
eth0.2:2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: What about vlan3?

Comment: vlan3 would be vlan3 . i ma trying to add a second vlan2

Comment: Is there any reason for trying to setup an alias vlan? Are you trying to assign a second IP to the interface?

Comment: Apart from that: Do you know that CentOS 6 is end of life software since 1,5 years ago? You should not use an OS which doesn't get any (security) updates!

Comment: "Is there any reason for trying to setup an alias vlan? Are you trying to assign a second IP to the interface? – " yes dynamic ones on vlan2

Comment: Would you mind adding that to your question? At the moment you are creating a [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/), where you ask about a possible solution for a problem, without describing the root of the problem. Please edit your question with the additional information